# A potential bug in the induction strategy of Frama-C 24.0

Tags: frama-c

I am working on the following proof and the invariant `result_val` is proved with an induction strategy on `i` using `begin` as the base case.

The `sup` case is trying to prove `true` which holds trivially using Frama-C 24.0. But when I switch to 25.0, it tries to prove a seemingly more complicated condition, which looks closer to a correct inductive inference because it did the weakest precondition computation explicitly.

However, all SMT solvers I tried cannot prove the condition generated by Frama-C 25.0.

I am a bit worried about the correctness of version 24.0's result because using `true` as the inductive proof goal seems to be unlikely. Can anyone hint to me at what happened? Is that a bug in 24.0 or just some difference in the implementation?

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#define  SIZE       1000

bool data[SIZE] ;


/*@
    logic integer count(integer begin, integer end)=
        begin >= end ? 0 : (data[begin]==true) ? count(begin+1, end)+1 : count(begin+1, end);
*/

/*@
    requires SIZE > begin >= 0;
    requires SIZE >= end >= 0;
    requires begin <= end;
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures \result == count(begin, end);
 */
unsigned int occurrences_of(int begin, int end)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;

    /*@
        loop invariant i_bound: begin <= i <= end;
        loop invariant result_bound: 0 <= result <= i-begin;
        loop invariant result_val: result == count(begin, i);
        loop assigns i, result;
        loop variant end-i;
    */
    for (unsigned int i = begin; i < end; ++i){
        result += (data[i] == true) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Below is the result from Frama-c 24.0

```
Proof:
  Goal Invariant 'result_val' (preserved) (Induction: proved)
   + Goal Induction (Base) (proved)
   + Goal Induction (Induction (sup)) (proved)
   + Goal Induction (Induction (inf)) (proved)
Qed.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Goal Induction (Induction (sup)):
Prove: true.
```

Below is the result from Frama-c 25.0

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Proof:
  Goal Invariant 'result_val' (preserved) (Induction: pending)
   + Goal Induction (Base) (proved)
   + Goal Induction (Induction (sup)) (pending)
   + Goal Induction (Induction (inf)) (proved)
End.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Goal Induction (Induction (sup)):
Let x_0 = to_uint32(end@L1).
Let x_1 = to_uint32(tmp@L12).
Let x_2 = data@L1[i@L6].
Let x_3 = result@L6.
Let x_4 = result@L13.
Let x_5 = to_uint32(1 + i@L6).
Assume {
  Have: begin@L1 < i@L6.
  Have: i@L6 <= end@L1.
  Have: i@L6 < x_0.
  Have: 0 <= x_3.
  Have: x_5 <= end@L1.
  Have: begin@L1 <= x_5.
  Have: (begin@L1 + x_3) <= i@L6.
  Have: (begin@L1 + x_4) <= x_5.
  Have: is_uint32(i@L6).
  Have: is_bool(x_2).
  Have: is_uint32(x_3).
  Have: if (x_2 = 1) then (tmp@L12 = 1) else (tmp@L12 = 0).
  Have: forall i_0 : Z. let x_6 = L_count(data@L1, begin@L1, i_0) in
      let x_7 = to_uint32(1 + i_0) in let x_8 = to_uint32(x_1 + x_6) in
      let x_9 = data@L1[i_0] in ((i_0 <= end@L1) -> ((begin@L1 <= i_0) ->
      ((i_0 < i@L6) -> ((i_0 < x_0) -> ((0 <= x_6) -> ((x_7 <= end@L1) ->
      ((begin@L1 <= x_7) -> (((begin@L1 + x_6) <= i_0) ->
      (((begin@L1 + x_8) <= x_7) -> (is_uint32(i_0) -> (is_bool(x_9) ->
      (is_uint32(x_6) ->
      ((if (x_9 = 1) then (tmp@L12 = 1) else (tmp@L12 = 0)) ->
      (L_count(data@L1, begin@L1, x_7) = x_8)))))))))))))).
  [...]
  Stmt { L6:  }
  Stmt { tmp = tmp_0;  }
  Stmt { L12: result = x_4;  }
  Stmt { L13:  }
}
Prove: L_count(data@L1, begin@L1, x_5) = x_4.

Goal id:  typed_occurrences_of_loop_invariant_result_val_preserved
Short id: occurrences_of_loop_invariant_result_val_preserved
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Prover Alt-Ergo 2.4.2: Timeout (Qed:52ms) (10s).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug on the typing of the induction tactic was indeed fixed between Frama-C 24 and 25 (https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/commit/6058453cce2715f7dcf9027767559f95fb3b1679). And the symptom was indeed that the tactic could generate ill-typed formulas with `true` instead of a term.

Proving this example in not that easy. For two main reasons:

- the function and the definition work in the opposite directions,
- the definition does not have an optimal expression for reasoning.

However, one can write a lemma function to solve the problem:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#define  SIZE       1000

bool data[SIZE] ;


/*@
    logic integer count(integer begin, integer end)=
        begin >= end ? 0 : ((data[begin]==true) ? count(begin+1, end)+1 : count(begin+1, end));
*/

/*@ ghost
  /@ requires begin < end ;
     assigns \nothing ;
     ensures count(begin, end) == ((data[end-1]==true) ? count(begin, end-1)+1 : count(begin, end-1));
  @/
  void lemma(bool* d, int begin, int end){
    /@ loop invariant begin <= i < end ;
       loop invariant count(i, end) == ((data[end-1]==true) ? count(i, end-1)+1 : count(i, end-1));
       loop assigns i ;
       loop variant i - begin ;
    @/
    for(int i = end-1 ; i > begin ;  i--);
  }
*/

/*@
    requires SIZE > begin >= 0;
    requires SIZE >= end >= 0;
    requires begin <= end;
    assigns \nothing;
    ensures \result == count(begin, end);
 */
unsigned int occurrences_of(int begin, int end)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;

    /*@
        loop invariant i_bound: begin <= i <= end;
        loop invariant result_bound: 0 <= result <= i-begin;
        loop invariant result_val: result == count(begin, i);
        loop assigns i, result;
        loop variant end-i;
    */
    for (unsigned int i = begin; i < end; ++i){
        result += (data[i] == true) ? 1 : 0;
        //@ ghost lemma(data, begin, i+1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'd suggest to use the following definition:

```c
/*@
    logic integer count(integer begin, integer end)=
        begin >= end ? 0 : ((data[end-1]==true) ? 1 : 0) + count(begin, end-1);
*/
```

It works in the same direction as the function and avoids the duplication of the term `count(begin, end-1)` which makes reasoning easier.

Comment: Thanks Ksass'Peuk. Now I see what is happened.